# Date format issue

Tags: apex, date, formatting

I have a visualforce calendar page which displays my date in correct Uk format (I am using the date function format()) with my Timezone as : (GMT+01:00) British Summer Time (Europe/London) , The Locale as :English (United Kingdom) and Language as : English . The same calendar page is also used by the Site Guest User.
Time zone for Site Guest User is : (GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) , Locale as :English (United Kingdom) and Language as :English.
The issue is that the same date format changes to US date format for the Site Guest User.In this case what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

Resolution To add a locale to the Vf page you need use the language attribute of Vf page.

It will use the locale according to the VF page language.

For example: apex:page  language="en_GB" , will use the UK- English locale and display the Date format as DD-MM-YY on Inputfield.

Reference:
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187671&language=en_US

Please see if this works for you

Comment: It is not an answer for the question, it is just a link for some external resource at the moment. You should describe the possible solution based on that resource. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to particular site >> `Public access setting` >> `Assigned User` >> `Site Guest User`. Then click on `Edit` and then change `Locale`. Click on the `Save` button.

Answer (score -1):

Resolution
To add a locale to the Vf page you need use the language attribute of Vf page.

It will use the locale according to the VF page language.

For example   will  use the UK- English locale and display the Date format as DD-MM-YY on Inputfield.

Comment: For example <apex:page  language[="en_GB">